# Google Pay returns strange error on Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-pay

I try to integrate Google Pay in my Xamarin.Forms shell application. I haven't found any tutorial without using stripe, only Kotlin one. I've tried to recreate example in my Payment class. Method Pay() looks like this:

```
var activity = Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
            client = WalletClass.GetPaymentsClient(activity, new WalletClass.WalletOptions.Builder()
                .SetEnvironment(WalletConstants.EnvironmentTest)
                .SetTheme(WalletConstants.ThemeLight)
                .Build());
            PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters param = PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.NewBuilder()
                .SetPaymentMethodTokenizationType(WalletConstants.PaymentMethodTokenizationTypePaymentGateway)
                .Build();
            PaymentDataRequest request =  PaymentDataRequest.NewBuilder()
                .SetEmailRequired(false)
                .SetShippingAddressRequired(false)
                .SetPhoneNumberRequired(false)
                .SetTransactionInfo(new TransactionInfo(1,"Test","Test"))
                .SetPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(param)
                .AddAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PaymentMethodTokenizedCard)
                .AddAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PaymentMethodCard)
                .SetCardRequirements(CardRequirements.NewBuilder()
                    .AddAllowedCardNetwork(WalletConstants.CardNetworkVisa)
                    .AddAllowedCardNetwork(WalletConstants.CardNetworkMastercard)
                    .Build())
                .Build();
            var data = await client.LoadPaymentDataAsync(request);
```

But after last line, Xamarin returns strange error `'6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown.'`. But I figure last line is supposed to show UI form from Google Pay, but somehow it doesn't work. I am using PlaySevices, Gms.Wallet and CurrentActivity plugins

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this yet but perhaps try the below to help you move forwards 
https://www.xamboy.com/2020/02/11/braintree-integration-in-xamarin-forms-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
var data = await client.LoadPaymentDataAsync(request);
```

With this (not async method):

```
var data = client.LoadPaymentData(request);
```

And pass it here (`53` can be anything, you will use that to identify this request):

```
AutoResolveHelper.ResolveTask(data, Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity, 53);
```

Then after the user actions the "card picking phase", you get results here in your MainActivity class:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
```

I found this link most helpfull and had success implementing:
https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?lang=java